# Передача POST из приложения на сервер

Tags: ajax, django, post, cors

Всем очень добрый день.

Есть приложение на django, к которому подключается сторонний плагин, написанный на js и php. Суть его в том, что пользователь заполняет форму, нажимает "отправить" и мне на почту приходит письмо с обращением пользователя. Проблема в том, что питоновский сервер не обрабатывает php, поэтому я подключил апач и указал ему директорию с php-скриптами, которые осуществляют функционал. Так вот, у меня никак не выходит отправить кроссдоменный запрос на сервер. Если использую jsonp, то браузер ругается на MIME type text/html:
[image: jsonp]

Если я использую заголовки, то получаю ошибку Response to preflight request:
[image: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

Я не силен в CORS, но насколько я понял, ошибка возникает на предполетном запросе, когда приложение и сервер обмениваются заголовками прежде чем начнется отправка данных. Как нужно прописать CORS, чтобы проверка прошла успешно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача POST из приложения на сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937008/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-post-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: Удалите предыдущий вопрос

Comment: 1) Воспользуйтесь кнопкой "Править", не нужно плодить один и тот же вопрос
2) Перестаньте вставлять код картинками.

Comment: Я так и намеревался сделать сначала. Но только кнопки такой не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, мало прописать заголовки в коде php, необходимо еще создать в корне приложения сервера .htaccess и прописать там Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*". После этого запросы прошли. А уже в php скрипте прописал доверенный домен, чтобы запросы проходили только с моего сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет установка пакета для django "django-cors-headers"

> A Django App that adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to responses.
>
> Although JSON-P is useful, it is strictly limited to GET requests.
>   CORS builds on top of XmlHttpRequest to allow developers to make
>   cross-domain requests, similar to same-domain requests.

https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/330943)

Comment: Эта ссылка ведет на указанный в ответе пакет, в которой указана инструкция по настройке этого же пакета, мне нужно было документацию пакета скопировать в ответ?

Comment: Да, конечно не полностью, основное.

Comment: Внес правки. Надеюсь так ответ станет более полезным.